# Is there an equivalent function in Twig to PHP's extract?

Tags: php, twig

I am in the process of converting several websites from a raw PHP templating system over to Twig.  One problem I have hit is how to convert templates where the PHP extract function is used.  Any thoughts on how to handle this?

Comment: Can't you just pass the extracted array to the twig render call? It should end up the same way, array keys as variable names.

Comment: Yup that is exactly what I did.  Write an answer and I will approve it.

Comment: In many years of PHP development, I have never come across a good reason to use the `extract()` function. It seems like it's primary purpose in life is to create security holes.

Comment: I am not exactly sure why it would create security holes, but is sure does make php template code much more readable.  It is also clear that Twig uses it in their render function, so...  Sorry you have not enjoyed this great function @Spudley. :-)

Comment: Just did a little research.  Yah if you are stupid enough to run extract on raw $_POST or $_GET data then you deserve to be hacked.  LOL.

Comment: @Spudley it's commonly used in templating systems, where they get an array of data to be available in the view. Of course you need to limit the scope of the extracted variables - do it in a function, where rendering the template is the only thing you do.

Comment: @NathanBunney - Yes, I have seen it used by a programmer doing exactly that, trying to make some old PHP code work in a newer environment with register_globals disabled. Needless to say, it was a bit of a facepalm moment when I found it.

Comment: Yikes, well the crackers need someone to laugh at. :P

Comment: Nobody has talked here about being hacked, this is necessary sometimes when updating all templates with thousands of instances strings with a stupid wrapper being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the array that you would otherwise call `extract()` on to twig's render function, in the end it will behave exactly like you need - the array's keys as the variable names.

Comment: What is this render function?

Comment: @enchance a function defined in `\Twig_Environment` that is responsibe for rendering a twig file.

Comment: Can you direct me to the docs on how to actually do this? I'm just looking for the best way to use Twig with my db queries. I'm still pretty lost.

Comment: That can be quite different depending on the framework you use (if you use any) and if you're using a database access layer. I'd read up on twig's own site, and if you have a question simply [ask one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Comment: How do I do this in Laravel??

Comment: This is a partial work-around, not an actual answer to the question. For example I'm trying to use an array (_context) passed to a macro in twig. There's an obvious reason to want to extract() it. The rendering doesn't even come into play in that example, and the question still stands.